# Is there a better alternative to CASE in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, case

I am working on the following SQL query (see below). Is there any better way to handle the conditional column "shipment_type"? I might have many more conditions to add, and the idea of repeating the same line over and over again looks pretty inefficient to me. Any suggestion?

```
SELECT
    u.user_id,
    u.user_email,
    o.order_id,
    o.product,
    o.amount,
    s.shipment_method,
    s.shipment_date,
    CASE
        WHEN s.shipment_comment LIKE '%international%' THEN 'international'
        WHEN s.shipment_comment LIKE '%worldwide%' THEN 'international'
        WHEN s.shipment_comment LIKE '%global%' THEN 'international'
        -- more conditions
        ELSE 'national'
    END AS shipment_type
FROM users AS u
    JOIN orders AS o 
        ON u.user_id = o.user_id
    JOIN shipments AS s
        ON s.order_id = o.order_id
WHERE
    u.country IN ('US', 'UK');
```

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: I am currently working with MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions.  In MySQL, this looks like:

```
(CASE WHEN s.shipment_comment regexp 'international|worldwide|global'
      THEN 'international'
      -- more conditions
      ELSE 'national'
 END) AS shipment_type
```

Postgres has similar functionality, but uses `~` instead of `REGEXP`.